# Как исправить код, чтобы не создавать лишние объекиы при каждой сортировке

Tags: java

существует такой метод:

```
public void find3MostResulted() {
    System.out.println("Choose football team: ");
    printFTH();
    int numFT = console.nextInt();

    footballTeamsAL.get(numFT - 1).footballersAL.sort(new AverageComparator());
}
```

Но, как я понял, его небольшая проблемка в том, что при сортировках создается много дополнительных объектов, я погуглил, пришел к выводу, что можно в классе "Footballer" объект класса AverageComparator сделать статическим полем. Я попытался, сделав так:

```
private String name; // имя футболиста
private int games, // количество игры в сезоне
            goals, // количество голов в сезоне
            assists, // количетсво голевых передач
            numFT,
            average;
 private static AverageComparator averageComparator;
```

Но, проблемы мне решить не удалось. Пршу вашей помощи. Для ясности картины прилагаю ниже весь код.

Класс Футболист

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
// футболист
public class Footballer {
private String name; // имя футболиста
private int games, // количество игры в сезоне
            goals, // количество голов в сезоне
            assists, // количетсво голевых передач
            numFT,
            average;
private static AverageComparator averageComparator;
public Footballer() {
    name = "No name";
    games = 0;
    goals = 0;
    assists = 0;
    average = (games + goals + assists) / 3; // тут всегда будет 0, но 
    для ясности логики прописал
}

public Footballer(String name, int games, int goals, int assists, 
@NotNull Football_team football_team) {
    this.name = name;
    this.games = games;
    this.goals = goals;
    this.assists = assists;
    this.numFT = football_team.getNum();
    this.average = (games + goals + assists) / 3;
}

public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
public void setGames(int games) { this.games = games; }
public void setGoals(int goals) { this.goals = goals; }
public void setAssists(int assists) { this.assists = assists;}

public String getName() { return name; }
public int getGames() { return games; }
public int getGoals() { return goals; }
public int getAssists() { return assists; }

public int getAverage() { return average; }

public void printFootballer() {
    System.out.print("Name: " + name + "\t" +
            "games: " + games + "\t" +
            "goals: " + goals + "\t" +
            "assists: " + assists + "\t" +
            "average: " + average + "\n\t"
    );
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name: " + name + "\t" +
            "games: " + games + "\t" +
            "goals: " + goals + "\t" +
            "assists: " + assists + "\t" +
            "average: " + average + "\n\t";
}
}
```

Класс "Футбольная команда"

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
//футбольная команда
public class Football_team {
protected ArrayList<Footballer> footballersAL = new ArrayList<>();

int num;

public Football_team() { num = 0; }
public  Football_team(int num) { this.num = num; }

public void setNum(int num) { this.num = num; }
public int getNum() { return num; }

public void printFootballTeam() {
    System.out.println("Football team number: " + num + "\n\t");
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Football team number: " + num + "\n\t";
}
}
```

Класс "Хендлер"

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
//обработчик
public class Handler {
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

private ArrayList<Football_team> footballTeamsAL = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Footballer> footballersAL = new ArrayList<>();

Football_team footballTeam;
Footballer footballer;

public void printFTH() {
    for(Football_team footballTeam1: footballTeamsAL) {
        System.out.print(footballTeam1.toString());
        System.out.println(footballTeam1.footballersAL.toString());
    }
}

public void createFootballTeam() {
    System.out.println("Enter the number of the football team: ");
    int num = console.nextInt();

    footballTeam = new Football_team(num);
    footballTeamsAL.add(footballTeamsAL.size(), footballTeam);
}

public void createFootballer() {
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the footballer: ");
    String name = console.next();

    System.out.println("Enter the number of the games in this season: ");
    int games = console.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the number of the goals in this season: ");
    int goals = console.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the number of the assists in this season: ");
    int assists = console.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Choose football team: ");
    printFTH();
    int numFT = console.nextInt();

    footballer = new Footballer(name, games, goals, assists, footballTeamsAL.get(numFT - 1));

    footballTeamsAL.get(numFT - 1).footballersAL.add(footballTeamsAL.get(numFT - 1).footballersAL.size(), footballer);
}

public void find3MostResulted() {
    System.out.println("Choose football team: ");
    printFTH();
    int numFT = console.nextInt();

    footballTeamsAL.get(numFT - 1).footballersAL.sort(new 
    AverageComparator()); 
}
}
```

Класс "Компаратор"

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import java.util.Comparator;
// класс, который необходим для сортировки массива футболистов по полю 
average в обратном порядке
// (от самого большого до саомго маленького)
public class AverageComparator implements Comparator<Footballer> {
public int compare(@NotNull Footballer f1, @NotNull Footballer f2) {
    return Integer.compare(f1.getAverage(), f2.getAverage());
}
```

}

Comment: Проблема выглядит надуманной.  Судя по вашему коду, вы создаёте объект компаратора ровно 1 раз (для одной команды).  Статический объект компаратора в классе футболиста является приватным и **неинициализированным**.

Comment: _Для ясности картины прилагаю ниже весь код._  **Весь** код с излишними геттерами/сеттерами/вводом с консоли, не относящимися к вопросу комментариями и прочими подробностями картину не проясняет, а затуманивает.  В вопросах следует приводить [минимальные самодостаточные примеры кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

Код действительно нужно исправить, но дело не в лишних объектах. Из вопроса даже непонятно, что именно вы имеете в виду под "лишними объектами". Насколько я понял, это объекты компаратора. Не думаю, что это проблема. То есть это в принципе может быть проблемой, но это точно не ваш случай. В вашем случае об этом нужно забыть и сконцентрироваться на читаемости кода. Главное - чистый код, про остальное забудьте пока не станете минимум синьерным разработчиком.
В любом случае для вашего спокойствия могу сказать, что в современном мире (с появлением java 8, что произошло довольно давно) отдельные классы - компараторы встречаются достаточно редко, поскольку их заменили лямбды.
Посему ознакомьтесь с данной версией кода, сравните ее со своей и поппробуйте понять, почему сделаны именно такие изменения. Если появятся вопросы - обращайтесь.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Handler {

    private final Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    private final List<FootballTeam> footballTeamsAL = new ArrayList<>();
    
    private void printFTH() {
        for (int i = 0; i < footballTeamsAL.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print((i + 1) + ". " + footballTeamsAL.get(i));
            System.out.println(footballTeamsAL.get(i).getFootballersAL());
        }
    }

    public void createFootballTeam() {
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the football team: ");
        footballTeamsAL.add(new FootballTeam(console.nextLine()));
    }

    public void createFootballer() {
        
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the footballer: ");
        String name = console.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the number of the games in this season: ");
        int games = console.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the number of the goals in this season: ");
        int goals = console.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the number of the assists in this season: ");
        int assists = console.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Choose football team: ");
        printFTH();
        int numFT = console.nextInt();
        
        FootballTeam footballTeam = footballTeamsAL.get(numFT - 1);

        Footballer footballer = new Footballer(name, games, goals, assists, footballTeam);
        footballTeam.addtFootballer(footballer);
    }

    public List<Footballer> findMostResulted(int mostNumber) {
        System.out.println("Choose football team: ");
        printFTH();
        int numFT = console.nextInt();        
        return footballTeamsAL.get(numFT - 1).chooseBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Footballer::getAverage), mostNumber);
    }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FootballTeam {

    private final List<Footballer> footballersAL = new ArrayList<>();
    
    private final String name;
    
    public FootballTeam(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public List<Footballer> getFootballersAL() {
        return footballersAL;
    }

    public void addtFootballer(Footballer footballer) {
        footballersAL.add(footballer);
    }
    
    public List<Footballer> chooseBy(Comparator<Footballer>comparator) {
        return chooseBy(comparator, 0);
    }
    
    public List<Footballer> chooseBy(Comparator<Footballer> comparator, int limit) {
        final int realLimit = limit == 0 ? footballersAL.size() : limit;
        return footballersAL.stream()
                .sorted(comparator)
                .limit(realLimit)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Football team name: " + name;
    }
}


public class Footballer {

    private String name; // имя футболиста
    private int games; // количество игры в сезоне
    private int goals; // количество голов в сезоне
    private int assists; // количетсво голевых передач
    private FootballTeam footballTeam;

    public Footballer(String name, int games, int goals, int assists, FootballTeam footballTeam) {
        this.name = name;
        this.games = games;
        this.goals = goals;
        this.assists = assists;
        this.footballTeam = footballTeam;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setGames(int games) {
        this.games = games;
    }

    public void setGoals(int goals) {
        this.goals = goals;
    }

    public void setAssists(int assists) {
        this.assists = assists;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getGames() {
        return games;
    }

    public int getGoals() {
        return goals;
    }

    public int getAssists() {
        return assists;
    }

    public FootballTeam getFootballTeam() {
        return footballTeam;
    }

    public void setFootballTeam(FootballTeam footballTeam) {
        this.footballTeam = footballTeam;
    }

    public int getAverage() {
        return (games + goals + assists) / 3;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + "\t"
                + "games: " + games + "\t"
                + "goals: " + goals + "\t"
                + "assists: " + assists + "\t"
                + "average: " + getAverage();
    }
}
```